# Ajax Search Return Problems

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make AJAX search calls as the user types a course name...
So far, I have the following problem:

My database design is as follows:

```
TABLE COURSE (
  Subject VARCHAR,
  Number CHAR(6)
)
```

Courses such as MATH 101 and BIOL 301B are stored as: 
Subject: MATH, Number: 101 
Subject: BIOL, Number: 301B

Now the problem is in PHP, I'm querying the db as follows:
`SELECT * FROM COURSE WHERE Subject LIKE :subject AND Number LIKE :number`

If I use `AND` in the SELECT statement, then if the user hasn't yet typed the full course title then he would not get any result...

Example Input: math 
In that case, I want all the MATH courses to show but since I'm using `AND` they won't...

Now if I use `OR` it's a different problem; Example Input: math 200 
This will return any courses with Number 200 which is not right!

How do you suggest I resolve this issue?

One solution that I have in mind is to have different functions that handle the searches differently and then combine the results...

Comment: When you type math you want to get all math subjects that you have in your database regardless the number ?

Comment: @frz3993 yes usually that's a typical ajax search result... type math and you should get all math courses.. type math 2 and you should get all math courses with number that begins with 2.. type m and you should get math and mech (mechanical engineering) courses all together

Comment: Your answer is in your question.  You need some if/then logic to check user input and build the query around what is or isn't present.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate both the `Subject` and `Number` and apply `LIKE` this way:

```
SELECT * FROM `course`
  WHERE CONCAT(`Subject`, ' ', `Number`) LIKE '%math%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try concatenating the values of columns `Subject` and `Number` in the query and then apply `LIKE` clause on that concatenated string.

Like this :

```
SELECT * FROM `course` WHERE CONCAT(Subject, ' ', Number) LIKE ('%math%');
```